# 'npm run build' have these errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I think my node version and npm version are too low ,but I got node 6.1.0 version ,there are same errors,I try to npm clear cache,npm i,or rm node_module,no use?

[Snap shot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weYUm.png)